# How to set value of div in javascript template tmpl

Tags: javascript, jquery-templates

I use the file upload plugin from Blueimp. In template download, I want to write value into

```
<div id="status"></div>
```

each time when template is render.

The div tag is put outside the form tag.
This is a script template download:

```
<script id="template-download" type="text/x-tmpl">
    {% 
        var location = document.getElementById("hdnLocation").value;
        var folder = document.getElementById("hdnFolder").value;
    %}

    {% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}    
        <div class="template-download fade clear-fix" data-value="{%=location%}\{%=folder%}\{%=file.name%}">
        ... do something ...
        {%
            document.getElementById("status").value = "TPL";
        %}
    </div>
    {% } %}

</script>
```

location and folder, I can get value but trying to set value is failed.

Comment: try document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "TPL";

Comment: Yes, it will work. My bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
document.getElementById("status").value = "TPL";
```

You need to use `innerHTML` not `value`

```
document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "TPL";
```

`.value` is a property assigned to `input` elements like `input`, `select`, `textarea`

Comment: Ops! my bad, I don't notice it. Thank you very much for your answer :)

Comment: I have a variable location. I want concat it to: location + "TPL". But it throws exception

Comment: You'll either need to be more specific or post a new question for that I'm not sure what you're asking :(

Comment: Like this: {%
        var link = location + folder + file.name;
        document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = link;
    %} it works. But {%
        var link = location + folder + "\" + file.name;
        document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = link;
    %} it throw exception

Comment: try adding another \ like this:  `... + "\\" + ...`

Comment: thank you, it will ignore if I have only first "\". Now it work like you said. Thank you very much